# Are these two algebras isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm wondering if $A_1 = \mathbf{C}[x_1,..,x_4]/(x_1x_3 - x_2x_4)$ is isomorphic to $A_2 = \mathbf{C}[x_1,..,x_4]/(x_1x_3 + x_2x_4)$.

I think so because I could send all the $x_i$ to $x_i$ for $i \neq 2$, and send $x_2$ to $-x_2$.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is correct.